# Is there a Broadcast Receiver concept in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have developed many apps on Android, and I have tried using Broadcast Receiver concept in many of them such as knowing when the battery is low or such.

I would like to use the same concept in developing on Windows phone, but I could not find Broadcast Receiver in it.

I want my application to know whenever the user took a new photo by camera. In addition, keep tracking of it.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I removed the `android`, `windows` and `phone` tag, since this post is related to `windows-phone` (which tag I added).

Answer (score 0):

There’s no broadcast receiver concept in Windows Phone.

IMO, this is by design.

I know two good reasons why I wouldn’t want that on my phone: privacy (almost no one reads list while installing apps) and battery life.

You can read those photos while your app is running (caching file list+modified times for faster updates).

And/or, you might want to create a lens extension, [here’s a link for WP8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662936(v=vs.105).aspx).